# Any way to guarantee the order of objects returned by FindObjectsOfType?

Tags: unity, c#, level-design

I wanted to create my spawn points for NPC's and also the player inside my 3D modelling software. So when I import each level, it has its own set of spawn points already built in.

This seems to work fine for me so far. But I had intended to use the FindObjectsOfType function. The problem is its important that I set the points in order (ie. spawn1 at bottom ... spawn 4 at top).

My problem is that the first element in the array is not my 'spawn_1', in my case here it is actually spawn2 first.

This is my hierarchy:
[image]

beer_tap_stand 1-4 are the spawn points in question at the moment, as you can see they are in order.

Then i have this code trying to spawn the player at 'beer_tap 1' :

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameManager instance;

    Customer_SpawnPoint[] customer_spawns;
    Beer_Tap_Standpoint[] beertap_standpoints;

    Player playerPrefab;
    Player player;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = this;
        else
            Destroy(this);

        customer_spawns = FindObjectsOfType<Customer_SpawnPoint>();
        beertap_standpoints = FindObjectsOfType<Beer_Tap_Standpoint>();
        playerPrefab = Resources.Load<Player>("Player");
        player = Instantiate(playerPrefab, beertap_standpoints[0].transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

    }
}
```

I need a way to guarantee the order, but I can't just drag them to the script as I have multiple levels.

Comment: Did you consider simply using System.Array.Sort to sort the results by name?

Comment: Sorry I have not been online to see these comments. I didn't use any sorting function to sort them. Solely the FindObjectsOfType() function so far

Comment: I'll try the System.Array.Sort solution first. Seems like it will be simple. Thank you for all responses.

Comment: I'm still trying to learn about Lambda functions, they confuse the heck outta me! But is this one of those times I need it to use in the Array.Sort() function? I have seen the detailed answer from Aybe, but just checking there isnt some magic one-line solution. Sorry to be a pain

Comment: In this case, could you use the findobjectswithtag function, or does this rely on hiarchy order too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You want a hierarchical sort using `Comparer<Transform>` with `GetSiblingIndex`:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Linq;
using JetBrains.Annotations;
using UnityEngine;

namespace xyz
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Hierarchical comparisons utility.
    /// </summary>
    public static class HierarchyComparer
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     Gets an instance that compares a hierarchy of <see cref="UnityEngine.Component" />.
        /// </summary>
        [PublicAPI]
        public static System.Collections.Generic.Comparer<Component> Component { get; } = new Comparer<Component>(Compare);

        /// <summary>
        ///     Gets an instance that compares a hierarchy of <see cref="UnityEngine.GameObject" />.
        /// </summary>
        [PublicAPI]
        public static System.Collections.Generic.Comparer<GameObject> GameObject { get; } = new Comparer<GameObject>(Compare);

        /// <summary>
        ///     Gets an instance that compares a hierarchy of <see cref="UnityEngine.Transform" />.
        /// </summary>
        [PublicAPI]
        public static System.Collections.Generic.Comparer<Transform> Transform { get; } = new Comparer<Transform>(Compare);

        private static int Compare([CanBeNull] Component x, [CanBeNull] Component y)
        {
#pragma warning disable IDE0031 // Null check can be simplified
            return Compare(x != null ? x.transform : null, y != null ? y.transform : null);
#pragma warning restore IDE0031
        }

        private static int Compare([CanBeNull] GameObject x, [CanBeNull] GameObject y)
        {
#pragma warning disable IDE0031 // Null check can be simplified
            return Compare(x != null ? x.transform : null, y != null ? y.transform : null);
#pragma warning restore IDE0031
        }

        private static int Compare([CanBeNull] Transform x, [CanBeNull] Transform y)
        {
            if (x == null && y == null)
                return 0;

            if (x == null)
                return -1;

            if (y == null)
                return +1;

            var hierarchy1 = GetHierarchy(x);
            var hierarchy2 = GetHierarchy(y);

            while (true)
            {
                if (!hierarchy1.Any())
                    return -1;

                var pop1 = hierarchy1.Pop();

                if (!hierarchy2.Any())
                    return +1;

                var pop2 = hierarchy2.Pop();

                var index1 = pop1.Index;
                var index2 = pop2.Index;

                if (index1 == index2)
                    continue;

                var compare = index1.CompareTo(index2);

                return compare;
            }
        }

        private static Stack<Hierarchy> GetHierarchy([NotNull] Transform transform)
        {
            if (transform == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(transform));

            var stack = new Stack<Hierarchy>();

            var current = transform;

            while (current != null)
            {
                var index = current.GetSiblingIndex();

                stack.Push(new Hierarchy(index, current));

                current = current.parent;
            }

            return stack;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Hierarchically sort an array of components.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="components"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [PublicAPI]
        public static Component[] HierarchicalSort([NotNull] this Component[] components)
        {
            if (components == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(components));

            Array.Sort(components, Component);

            return components;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Hierarchically sort an array of game objects.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameObjects"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [PublicAPI]
        public static GameObject[] HierarchicalSort([NotNull] this GameObject[] gameObjects)
        {
            if (gameObjects == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(gameObjects));

            Array.Sort(gameObjects, GameObject);

            return gameObjects;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Hierarchically sort an array of transforms.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="transforms"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [PublicAPI]
        public static Transform[] HierarchicalSort([NotNull] this Transform[] transforms)
        {
            if (transforms == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(transforms));

            Array.Sort(transforms, Transform);

            return transforms;
        }

        #region Nested type: Comparer

        private sealed class Comparer<T> : System.Collections.Generic.Comparer<T>
        {
            public Comparer([NotNull] Func<T, T, int> func)
            {
                Func = func ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(func));
            }

            private Func<T, T, int> Func { get; }

            public override int Compare(T x, T y)
            {
                return Func(x, y);
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Nested type: Hierarchy

        private struct Hierarchy
        {
            public int Index { get; }

            [SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "MemberCanBePrivate.Local", Justification = "debugging")]
            public Transform Target { get; }

            public Hierarchy(int index, [NotNull] Transform transform)
            {
                if (index < 0)
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));

#pragma warning disable IDE0016 // Null check can be simplified
                if (transform == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(transform));
#pragma warning restore IDE0016

                Index = index;
                Target = transform;
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return $"{nameof(Index)}: {Index}, {nameof(Target)}: {Target}";
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Throw that to an array of transforms, they will always be sorted in hierarchy order.

**Edit:**

Refined version, minor adjustments, supports any `Component`, less code but functionally identical:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using JetBrains.Annotations;
using UnityEngine;

namespace xyz
{
    public static class HierarchicalSorting
    {
        private static int Compare([CanBeNull] Component x, [CanBeNull] Component y)
        {
            return Compare(x != null ? x.transform : null, y != null ? y.transform : null);
        }

        private static int Compare([CanBeNull] GameObject x, [CanBeNull] GameObject y)
        {
            return Compare(x != null ? x.transform : null, y != null ? y.transform : null);
        }

        private static int Compare([CanBeNull] Transform x, [CanBeNull] Transform y)
        {
            if (x == null && y == null)
                return 0;

            if (x == null)
                return -1;

            if (y == null)
                return +1;

            var hierarchy1 = GetHierarchy(x);
            var hierarchy2 = GetHierarchy(y);

            while (true)
            {
                if (!hierarchy1.Any())
                    return -1;

                var pop1 = hierarchy1.Pop();

                if (!hierarchy2.Any())
                    return +1;

                var pop2 = hierarchy2.Pop();

                var compare = pop1.CompareTo(pop2);

                if (compare == 0)
                    continue;

                return compare;
            }
        }

        [NotNull]
        private static Stack<int> GetHierarchy([NotNull] Transform transform)
        {
            if (transform == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(transform));

            var stack = new Stack<int>();

            var current = transform;

            while (current != null)
            {
                var index = current.GetSiblingIndex();

                stack.Push(index);

                current = current.parent;
            }

            return stack;
        }

        [PublicAPI]
        [NotNull]
        [ItemNotNull]
        public static T[] Sort<T>([NotNull] [ItemNotNull] T[] components) where T : Component
        {
            if (components == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(components));

            Array.Sort(components, new RelayComparer<T>(Compare));

            return components;
        }

        [PublicAPI]
        [NotNull]
        [ItemNotNull]
        public static GameObject[] Sort([NotNull] [ItemNotNull] GameObject[] gameObjects)
        {
            if (gameObjects == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(gameObjects));

            Array.Sort(gameObjects, new RelayComparer<GameObject>(Compare));

            return gameObjects;
        }

        [PublicAPI]
        [NotNull]
        [ItemNotNull]
        public static Transform[] Sort([NotNull] [ItemNotNull] Transform[] transforms)
        {
            if (transforms == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(transforms));

            Array.Sort(transforms, new RelayComparer<Transform>(Compare));

            return transforms;
        }

        private sealed class RelayComparer<T> : Comparer<T>
        {
            public RelayComparer([NotNull] Func<T, T, int> func)
            {
                Func = func ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(func));
            }

            [NotNull]
            private Func<T, T, int> Func { get; }

            public override int Compare(T x, T y)
            {
                return Func(x, y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems perfect. Will try to implement this immediately. Thank you

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly! I can't claim to fully understand the magic yet but I understood parts of it. Very helpful mate! I just needed to add this class to my project and then before I use the array in my code i added line: HierarchyComparer.HierarchicalSort(beertap_standpoints); I will study your class further and hope to gain more knowledge from it.

Comment: Glad it helped you out

Comment: @I_Keep_Trying I've reworked a much simpler to understand but functionally identical version, added below original.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `LevelManager` script. That script should have an array in the inspector where you can drag the spawnpoints specific to that level. Add the `LevelManager` to all of your levels.

```
public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Customer_SpawnPoint[] customer_spawns;
    public Beer_Tap_Standpoint[] beertap_standpoints;
}
```

Then in your `GameManager` script, you can find that level's `LevelManager` with `var myLevelManager = FindObjectOfType<LevelManager>();`. Now you can use the spawnpoints with `myLevelManager.customer_spawns`, and they will be in the same order as you dragged them in the inspector.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. However I am trying to find a way of avoiding drag-drop properties in the Inspector.

Answer (score 1):

> I have seen the detailed answer from Aybe, but just checking there isnt some magic one-line solution.

```
var objects = FindObjectsOfType<SomeType>();
System.Array.Sort(objects, (a, b) => a.name.CompareTo(b.name));
```

> I'm still trying to learn about Lambda functions, they confuse the heck outta me! But is this one of those times I need it to use in the Array.Sort() function?

No, you can do it without a lambda. Just define an ordinary named function that takes two components as parameters and returns an integer representing their relative sort order. (You can exchange a & b or negate the return value if you want to sort in the opposite order)

```
static int CompareComponentNames(Component a, Component b) {
    return a.name.CompareTo(b.name);
}

// ...later, when you have an array you want to sort:

System.Array.Sort(objects, CompareComponentNames);
```

Comment: wonderful. I figured there would be some way to do it with the lambda (not sure how I managed to know that though lol). Now I think I understand them a little better. Thanks